# My brothers have tried to kill my husband - how can I seek asylum in another country?

Tags: immigration, safety, indian-citizens, asylum

I am from India and hold an Indian passport.

I ran away from home and married a guy and then ran away with him to another country but after couple of days I came back after my family put pressure on my husband's family through police and they filed a missing person case for me.  After I came back he also returned next day and we got married but still I have problem with my 7 brothers I am the only sister. A couple of times they tried to kill him using some other persons and I am afraid to be here any longer as even my parents won't help me.  I am pregnant but live in my friend's aunt's home with but still I fear they will find us.

I would like to apply for asylum in any country like Australia, USA or where ever I could be safe.  How could I go about it?

Comment: As far as I know, you basically need to reach the country in question to lodge an application. Unfortunately, it seems your situation does not fit the usual criteria for asylum.

Comment: I'm probably asking a very naive question, but could any domestic organisations (governmental or non-governmental) be of help?

Comment: Let's say you managed to get asylum and moved to another country, what stops your family from putting pressure again?

Comment: You should not have come back.

Comment: u can't apply for asylum to any country unless you get to that country first. even then, you would need to produce a lot of proof like police statements about the attempt to murder etc. Indians are not generally granted asylum anywhere.

Answer (score 12):

Asylum is usually given for *government* persecution. As long as you can live in your country without the government severely persecuting you (hanging you by the neck for being gay, for example), asylum is unlikely. You'll have to deal with your family through the local authorities.

Comment: Alternatively, India is a big place and it may be possible to move away to somewhere else.